# How can I query a table between two dates that can be null?

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle10g

I have two text box which I can get start & end dates from user.
There are 3 condition here.

- User can fill 2 text box
- User can fill only start date (end date is empty).
- User can fill only end date (start date is empty).

And finally, What should my query be?

Variables: `start_date` and `end_date`

Query: `SELECT  *  FROM kkmail WHERE MAIL_DATE ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM kkmail 
WHERE (MAIL_DATE >= @start_date OR @start_date is null)
and (MAIL_DATE <= @end_date OR @end_date is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has [LNNVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions078.htm) function to write these type of queries in a concise way, although a little confusing.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM kkmail 
 WHERE lnnvl(mail_date < @start_date)
   AND lnnvl(mail_date > @end_date);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/90)